# On update gridview row=current edited Row value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like on gridview update to get a value from a cell in the edited row for GridView1.Rows[get the edited row ].Cells[3];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the [`RowUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) event:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {    
    GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String fourthCellstext = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    // .....
 }
```

Comment: I want to check on row update , so if the user is writing something into that cell and he press UPDate , then something will happen

Comment: So have you read when `RowUpdating` occurs, i've provided the link above? _"The RowUpdating event is raised when a row's Update button is clicked."_

Comment: oh I thought the row updated event is raised when the row's update was clicked.

Comment: @InziIrina: Again, i've linked (and showed code for) the **`RowUpdating`**, not the **`RowUpdated`** event ;)

Comment: so basicly , I'm getting the value from the third cell of the updated row? sorry I can't test becauses I'm not home